# iphone-sdk: Adding a textfield to UIAlertview does not work in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitextfield, uialertview

I am trying to add `uitextfield` to my `alterview`. When the user tries to enter text the `alterview` is supposed to shift up a little bit so the keyboard does not overlap and when pressing the done key the keyboard is supposed to disappear and the `alertview` should shift back.

It all works fine when run it in iOS 3.1.2 (and also in 3.2) but as soon as I try to run it under iOS 4 the `alertview` is displayed in the wrong position and the keyboard won't disappear. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
- (void)addItemAction{

workoutName = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Workout" message:@"Insert the name of your new workout:\n                " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
workoutName.cancelButtonIndex = 0;
UITextField *titleField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 90.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
titleField.delegate = self;
titleField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
titleField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[workoutName addSubview:titleField];
[workoutName show];


}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {


[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -70.0);
[workoutName setTransform:myTransform];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
[workoutName setTransform:myTransform];
[UIView commitAnimations];
self.newWorkout = textField.text;

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    if (self.newWorkout != @"TestWorkout"){
    [self.workoutPlanArray insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.newWorkout, @"titleValue", @"04.08.10", @"dateValue", nil] atIndex:counter];
    counter++;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also using alertview with a textfield in my application, & that too on ioS 4.0.
 Its working fine.

Here is the sample code:_

```
-(void)showAlert{

showAlert=YES; //boolean variable

createNewAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ADD item" message:@"Put it blank textfield will cover this" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

UITextField *txtName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
txtName.text=@"";
[txtName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[txtName setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
[txtName setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

[txtName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[createNewAlert addSubview:txtName];


[createNewAlert show];
}
```

Also you can refer the following two methods which are called on Keyboard notifications.

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow: (id) notification {

if(showAlert==YES)
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [createNewAlert setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-60)];
    [createNewAlert show];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}

```
-(void)keyboardWillHide: (id) notification {

if(showAlert==YES) 
{


        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [createNewAlert setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,+60)];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem that is new in iOS 4 as well. I tried to do a translation on it and realized that it doesn't matter the translation, only that a translation was called.

```
myAlert = my AlertView
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f);
myAlert.transform = rotate;
[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
```

There must be a callback that gets fired from the translation but this fixes the problem.  It should act as it did in pre-iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue (yet) regarding the positioning of the alert, but you might try sending `resignFirstResponder` in your `textFieldShouldReturn` implementation to the `alertView`.

Also, that should make the keyboard disappear (even if I do not know exactly why).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner implementation of a UIAlertView coupled with a UITextField: [DDAlertPrompt](https://github.com/digdog/DDAlertPrompt) or [EGOTextFieldAlertView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextFieldAlertView).

Answer (score 0):

Open the `xib` file, click on the `UIView` and make sure that the "`User Interaction Enabled`" check box is ticked.