# Cocoa touch : Multiple line text input

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, textinput

In my `UIViewController <GLKViewDelegate>` in need to make a simple text input when selecting a object.

Is there in UIKit a simple multiline text input popup ready to use ?

I already found `UIAlertView` with `alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` but it's only a simple line input.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean is there an equivalent of the text input `UIAlertView` with a `UITextView` rather than a `UITextField`, the answer is no.

Comment: [Click here Ashley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410372/iphone-sdk-adding-a-textfield-to-uialertview-does-not-work-in-ios-4)

Comment: Absolutely you can roll your own, but the question was "**Is there in UIKit a simple multiline text input popup ready to use**", so the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. but I think [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you need.

**Edit**

*You can try this out*

***Set this in un .h file the the delegate like this***

```
@interface NameOfYourClass : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

***And add this code in un .m File***

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Sheet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Button" otherButtonTitles:@"Other Button 1", @"Other Button 2", nil];

    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

**Edit2**

So here's what to do to add a textfield to your allertview

```
UIAlertView *newAlert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ADD item" message:@"Put it blank textfield will cover this" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    UITextField *newTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    newTextField.text=@"";
    [newTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [newTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [newTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

    [newTextField setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [newAlert addSubview:newTextField];

    [newAlert show];
```

Comment: edited, you have to set the delegate of the actionSheet in your .h class

Comment: Ok I finally figured out what you need! the only way to have a alertview with more text fields is to create a custom alertview on the base of UIView