# UIAlertView Login and Password Input with three buttons

Tags: ios, uialertview

I just found a strange problem, when I try to use three buttons in an UIAlertView, the view is displayed weirdly, as you can see in this screenshot :

[image: UIAlertView]

Here is the code :

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login",@"Forget Password", nil];

[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
UITextField *place=[alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
place.placeholder=@"Email";
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Please suggest me how I can correct this. Thanks.

Comment: please post the code that you implemented

Comment: The following link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410372/iphone-sdk-adding-a-textfield-to-uialertview-does-not-work-in-ios-4